# SimpleSchema type for validating any Mongo Document returned from a Cursor

Tags: validation, meteor, simple-schema

What is the correct `SimpleSchema type` that should be used to validate *any* `Document` returned from a `Cursor`?

For example *any* cursor can be validated using:

```
{ type: Mongo.Cursor }
```

I have seen a package where the following is used, which works:

```
{ type: CollectionName._helpers }
```

But if I have a component that can accept *any* type of `Document`, so what would be the correct `type` to use here? I do not want to pass the collection in this case (already doing that in other cases), and just want to make sure it's a valid `Document` and not any other type like `Object`.

I apologize ahead of time if this was already answered, had no luck with searching here or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, this is not possible out of the box at the moment. [Here's](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/issues/31) a conversion on this topic.

You can probably handle this using [custom validation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#custom-validation) rules.